# moving from one column in a dataframe in pandas to many or many columns to one

Tags: pandas, dataframe, transform

I have a pandas dataframe with 20 items in it which I would like to reshape to 5 columns by 4 rows.

Is this possible with a pandas dataframe? And then is it possible to do the reverse and convert the resulting 5*4 dataframe into a 2*10 or 1*20?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use first [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) for converting to `numpy array` and then [`numpy.ndarray.reshape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,7,7],
                   'B':[4,5,6,8,0],
                   'C':[7,8,9,7,8],
                   'D':[1,3,5,8,1]})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D
0  1  4  7  1
1  2  5  8  3
2  3  6  9  5
3  7  8  7  8
4  7  0  8  1

df = pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(4,5),columns=list('ABCDE'))
print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E
0  1  4  7  1  2
1  5  8  3  3  6
2  9  5  7  8  7
3  8  7  0  8  1
```

---

```
print (df.values.reshape(10,2))
[[1 4]
 [7 1]
 [2 5]
 [8 3]
 [3 6]
 [9 5]
 [7 8]
 [7 8]
 [7 0]
 [8 1]]

print (pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(10,2), columns=list('AB')))
   A  B
0  1  4
1  7  1
2  2  5
3  8  3
4  3  6
5  9  5
6  7  8
7  7  8
8  7  0
9  8  1
```

EDIT by comment:

```
pos = [1,5,7,8,10,8]

print (pd.DataFrame(np.array(pos).reshape(2,3),columns=list('ABC')))
   A   B  C
0  1   5  7
1  8  10  8
```

Comment: what if you are passing something like a list into a dataframe, can you reshape it at the same time? For example if pos is my list I get an error with: pd.DataFrame(pos).reshape(4,5),columns=list('ABCDE'))

Comment: I think you need convert `list` to numpy array by `pd.DataFrame(np.array(pos).reshape(4,5),columns=list('ABCDE')) `